# RAID size problem after 'dd' from old array to new

Tags: partitioning, raid

I've added a new larger RAID 5 array (57TB) to my server and copied the old RAID 5 (20TB) using 'dd'.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
   Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
      md0 : active raid5 sdl1[6] sdk1[4] sdj1[3] sdi1[2] sdh1[1] sdg1[0]
      19534425600 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

      md1 : active raid5 sdc[2] sdd[3] sde[4] sdf[6] sda[0] sdb[1]
      57403632640 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/86 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

   unused devices: <none>
```

The problem is after the copy the old array (/dev/md0) has the same size as the new (/dev/md1). Which of course is impossible.

```
df
/dev/md0       19455645304 12996096208 5482811432  71% /oldarray
/dev/md1       19455645304 12996096208 5482811432  71% /md0
```

I think the problem may have something to do with partitioning. I did not partition the new RAID before creating it (mdadm).

```
lsblk
sda           8:0    1  10.7T  0 disk  
  └─md1         9:1    0  53.5T  0 raid5 /md0
sdb           8:16   1  10.7T  0 disk  
  └─md1         9:1    0  53.5T  0 raid5 /md0
sdc           8:32   1  10.7T  0 disk  
  └─md1         9:1    0  53.5T  0 raid5 /md0
sdd           8:48   1  10.7T  0 disk  
  └─md1         9:1    0  53.5T  0 raid5 /md0
sde           8:64   1  10.7T  0 disk  
  └─md1         9:1    0  53.5T  0 raid5 /md0
sdf           8:80   1  10.7T  0 disk  
  └─md1         9:1    0  53.5T  0 raid5 /md0
sdg           8:96   0   3.6T  0 disk  
  └─sdg1        8:97   0   3.6T  0 part  
       └─md0       9:0    0  18.2T  0 raid5 /oldarray
sdh           8:112  0   3.6T  0 disk  
  └─sdh1        8:113  0   3.6T  0 part  
       └─md0       9:0    0  18.2T  0 raid5 /oldarray
sdi           8:128  0   3.6T  0 disk  
  └─sdi1        8:129  0   3.6T  0 part  
       └─md0       9:0    0  18.2T  0 raid5 /oldarray
sdj           8:144  0   3.6T  0 disk  
  └─sdj1        8:145  0   3.6T  0 part  
       └─md0       9:0    0  18.2T  0 raid5 /oldarray
sdk           8:160  0   3.6T  0 disk  
  └─sdk1        8:161  0   3.6T  0 part  
       └─md0       9:0    0  18.2T  0 raid5 /oldarray
sdl           8:176  0   3.6T  0 disk  
  └─sdl1        8:177  0   3.6T  0 part  
       └─md0       9:0    0  18.2T  0 raid5 /oldarray
sdm           8:192  0   1.8T  0 disk  
  └─sdm1        8:193  0   1.8T  0 part
```

Can someone tell me how to untangle this without destroying the new array, if possible. I hate to have to do that copy again. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used dd, you copied the partition and filesystem info to the new array. You need to expand the partition on the new array, to use all the available space, and expand the filesystem as well. It's easiest to use gparted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can do that without destroying the data already there?